# Access SQL return nth row for each given field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

### My problem

Let's say I have a query that returns the following data:

```
id     date
--    ------
1     2015-01-12
1     ... // here I might have X more rows
1     2015-06-30
2     2015-01-12
2     ... // here I might have Y more rows
2     2015-05-20
...
```

Given that `X, Y >= 120 and X != Y` and the order of the query is `id, date ASC` I want a way to retrieve the record number 120 for id 1 and the 120 for the id 2 (and so on for each different ID), something like:

```
id      date
--    --------
1     2015-03-24 // this is the record 120 for id = 1
2     2015-04-26 // this is the record 120 for id = 2
...
```

Notice that the dates don't follow a sequential order (you may have a gap between one row and the next one).

**Is there a direct SQL solution for my problem?** (I know I can use vba to achieve my goal but I rather stay with SQL)

As a clarification note, see this example. Given the following resultset:

```
id     date
--    ------
1     2015-01-12  // this is record 1 for id = 1
1     2015-01-13  // this is record 2 for id = 1
1     2015-01-20  // this is record 3 for id = 1
1     2015-01-21  // this is record 4 for id = 1
...
1     2015-03-22  // this is record 118 for id = 1
1     2015-03-23  // this is record 119 for id = 1
1     2015-03-24  // this is record 120 for id = 1
1     2015-03-25  // this is record 121 for id = 1
...
1     2015-06-30  // this is the last row for id = 1
2     2015-01-12  // this is record 1 for id = 2
2     2015-01-13  // this is record 2 for id = 2
...
2     2015-04-25  // this is record 120 for id = 2
...
2     2015-05-20  // this is the last record for id = 2
```

The result should be:

```
id      date
--    --------
1     2015-03-24
2     2015-04-26
```

Remember, I have at least 120 records for each ID, this is a fact (I have a query that gives only the IDs with more than 119 records)

### Attempted solution

I've tried to play with the `SELECT TOP` directive, but I fail to achieve the results I want as I cannot apply it direcly: I don't want the top 120 and then get the last row as I want the last one of the TOP 120 for each ID.

### Edited for (a second) clarification

My goal would be to have something like:

```
SELECT id, 120thRow(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

unfortunatelly I don't know how to implement the *120thRow* function in access.

Comment: What is the record number?  Your question seems to be missing some important bit of information.  Is "120" in some column in the data?

Comment: Nope, I use the 120 criteria in another query to get the results. I tried (and failed) to explain that for each ID I have more than 120 records (that's a fact) and I want the record 120 for each ID. I'll try to edit and make it clearer

Comment: I think you should clarify more. Why there is 2015-03-24 besides id 1? It's not the first, not the last, not min or max. Why it is there?

Comment: @LaszloTenki, that's the tricky part. It's not the last, min or max. I need the 120 count and I don't have an autonumber as this is a query and the autonumeric field is broken. If it was directly a call from any aggregate function, that would be very easy with a group by and the aggregate.

Comment: Question again: you always need 120, even if you have more? It seems so, but I'd like to be sure. So when you have x, you need x when x <= 120 and 120 when x > 120?

Comment: Does the table's design permit only unique combinations of id and date?

Comment: @LaszloTenki, yes I always need the 120th row for each ID and I probably always would have more than 120th rows. The row number for each field would never be < 120, I filter the IDs which doesn't have 120 results.

Comment: @HansUp, the resultset comes from another query, if you want to take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190717/msaccess-sql-count-days-in-overlaping-periods-with-some-excluding-periods) is where all came from: it's a problem related to calculate (non consecutive) periods of time for a given entity (I've simplified my use case as it's more complex, actually I don't have an ID but the combination of 2 fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I've managed a way to put a row counter for each day and ID like so:

```
select id, date, 
       (
          select count(date) 
          from table As t1 
          where t1.id = t.id
            and t1.date <= t.date
       ) As rowNum
from table As t
```

From here on it's just a matter of selecting from this resultset the rows which has rownum = 120 and game over.

Comment: i know you've wound up using count, but did you manage to find a better solution - a purer one? people many years later would love to see this answer, it's such a good question...........

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, No, I'm still using this query in a internal calculation. If someone has a better idea I'm all ears :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work in Access?

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.date = (select top 1 date
                from (select top 120 date
                      from table t2
                      where t2.id = t.id
                      order by date
                     ) as tt
                order by date desc
               );
```

EDIT:

I guess MS Access doesn't allow nesting in the correlation clause.  You can do this more painfully as:

```
select t.*
from table as t join
     (select t.id, max(t.date) as maxdate
      from table as t
      where t.date = (select top 120 date
                      from table as t2
                      where t2.id = t.id
                      order by date
                     )
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id and t.date = tt.maxdate;
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. First of all I get ```syntax error``` as there is a reference to ```t2.id``` but no *t2* alias. I've tried using *t1*, *t2* and *t3* for alias, but I got error with the inner query, access is asking for the t.id field (well *t1.id* if I followed you well).

Comment: @mTorres . . . I wan't positive if this would work.  I guess Access doesn't allow nesting of the correlation clause.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my previous answer, I misunderstood you. I have another approach but in SQL. I am almost sure that it does not work in Access but might give you an idea.

```
-- start: this is just preparation of some sample data
declare @t table (id int, date datetime)
declare @id int, @d datetime, @c int
set @c = 0
set @id = 1
set @d = '2015-01-01'
while @c <= 125
    begin
    insert into @t values (@id, @d)
    set @d = dateadd(day, 1, @d)
    set @c = @c + 1
    end
set @c = 0
set @id = 2
set @d = '2015-01-02'
while @c <= 125
    begin
    insert into @t values (@id, @d)
    set @d = dateadd(day, 1, @d)
    set @c = @c + 1
    end
-- end: this is just preparation of some sample data

-- this is somewhat like what you need:
select id, date from 
(select id, date, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as rc from @t) as mytable
where rc = 120
```

Comment: Sorry man, using the aggregate function isn't helpful as I want the 120th record for each ID, nor the min neither the max, the 120th for each ID.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. It was not clear for me sorry.

Comment: But are you using an index? Because it might not be deterministic without that, so it is changing what row is the 120th.

Comment: I cannot use an index as this is not based directly on one table but a resultset from another query which blows away my indices. My resultset comes from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28190931/1013219).

Comment: I changed my answer to give you some idea, but it's SQL and not really Access.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly this is not working in access. You deserve a +1 for trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this must work for you.

```
with Records AS
(select row_number() over(order by sort_column_name) as 'row', * 
       from table_name) select * from records where row=n
```

- `sort_column_name` – mention the name of the column which is sorting the table.
- `n` – row number
- `table_name` – mention the name of the table table name